# Delete the data based on the output of awk command

Tags: awk

I have a file `test.dat` with delimited text. Delimiter is `|` containing 4 columns in a file. But due to some issue, there is some discrepancy in the number of columns for some of the rows. I have found those rows using `awk` command. Now I need to delete those rows.

test.dat:

```
a|b|c|d
a|b|c
a|b|c|d|e
```

I found rows with:

```
awk -F "|" 'NF!=4' test.dat
```

Result:

```
a|b|c
a|b|c|d|e
```

Now I need to delete this from the file.
Any pointers. I used `xargs` but didn't work.

Comment: Why just not printing the lines you need: `awk -F"|" 'NF==4' test.dat >output.dat`?

Comment: Why not just post an answer as an answer instead of a comment?